# CLT for martingale difference array

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I am concerned with CLTs for m.d.a. A famous result is due to McLeish (https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176996608). The notes from Sethuraman (http://math.arizona.edu/~sethuram/notes/wi_mart1.pdf) are very helpful to understand the proof. I have two questions:

1. I have a problem with their conditions on the m.d.a.

Let $(X_{ni})_{i=1}^{k_n}$ be a m.d.a.

- McLeish's conditions: 
  (i) $\max_{i\le k_n} |X_{ni}|$ converges in probability to $0$ (as $n\to\infty$)
  (ii) $\max_{i\le k_n} |X_{ni}|$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2$ and (iii) $\sum_{i\le k_n}X_{ni}^2$ converges is probability to 1.
- Sethuramans conditions: (i) $\max_{i\le k_n} |X_{ni}|$ converges in $L^1$ to $0$ and (iii) from McLeish.

I don't see why (i) and (ii) from McLeish is equivalent(?) to (i) from Sethuraman, although the proof is basically the same and Sethurman is always refering to McLeish's paper.

2. In Thm3 Sethuraman looks at a special case (ergodic and stationary sequence) and concludes that condition (ii) (=(iii) from McLeish) follows from the ergodicity of the sequence. By the ergodic theorem I know (using his notations) that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_i\to E(Z_1)$ a.s., but can I therefore conclude $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_i^2\to E(Z_1^2)$ a.s.?

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
$$\require{cancel} \left. \begin{array}{l}
     \text{pr-}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\max_{i\le k_n}|X_{ni}|=0,\\
     \sup\limits_{n}\sup\limits_{i\le k_n}\mathsf{E}[X_{ni}|^2\le C<\infty.\end{array}
\right\} \stackrel{\implies}{\cancel{\impliedby}}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}[\max_{i\le k_n}|X_{ni}|]=0,$$
since $\mathsf{E}[X^2_{ni}]$ deals with the second order moment.

**2.** Let $\{Z_n,n\in\mathbb{N}_+\}$ be a ergodic stationary sequence, then 
for any nonegative Borel-measurable function $f$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(Z_i)=\mathsf{E}[f(Z_1)]. \qquad\text{a.s.}$$
cf. O. Kallenberg, *Foundations of Modern Probability*, 2ed. Springer Verlag, 2001. Th.10.6, p.181. 
Taking $f(x)=x^2$ give what you want.